# Setting Multiple DataKeyNames in GridView from different ActiveRecord table objects

Tags: gridview, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to set two datakeys using the DataKeyNames property of an asp.net GridView.

I have a simplequery as follows:

```
Castle.ActiveRecord.Queries.SimpleQuery<ARMapping.CONFIGURATION> c = new Castle.ActiveRecord.Queries.SimpleQuery<ARMapping.CONFIGURATION>(@"
            select c from CONFIGURATION c left join c.LUserConfiguration luc left join luc.User u left join u.Dealer d left join c.TRUCK t");
```

In the databind operation, the dealership would be evaluated as follows:

`<`% Eval("LUserConfiguration.User.Dealer.DealershipID") %`>`

But when I try to set DataKeyNames="ID,LUserConfiguration.User.Dealer.DealershipID", I get error:
" DataBinding: 'ARMapping.CONFIGURATION' does not contain a property with the name 'LUserConfiguration.User.Dealer.DealershipID'. "

It doesn't complain when it's Eval'd, but I can't put Eval in the DataKeyNames property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Following [the pattern outlined here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1121279/1944030.aspx#1944030), I was able to solve the problem.

A brief explanation...  I created a new partial class of the CONFIGURATION class (I did this because my ActiveRecord code is auto-generated, and I couldn't change it.  I'm sure this is highly suggested usage anyway, as your models almost always have extended functionality that a partial class is perfect for.

The partial class follows:

```
Partial Public Class CONFIGURATION

    Public ReadOnly Property GetDealerID() As Integer
        Get
            Return LUserConfigurations.Item(0).Users.Dealer.ID
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then, I set the DataKeyNames attribute of the GridView to "ID,GetDealerID".  I haven't tested, but the page is loading without error now.

You have to make sure you create a *property*, not a function (according to the link above).